# List Google Workspace users with a service account using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to consume Google Directory API from a simple script using a Service Account.
The script should be able to list the users from Google Workspace.

I have configured a project with a service account and generated the key.
And I have enabled the Admin SDK API.

The script:

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");

(async () => {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: "credentials.json",
    scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly"],
  });

  const service = google.admin({ version: "directory_v1", auth });
  const res = await service.users.list({
    customer: "my_customer",
    maxResults: 10,
    orderBy: "email",
  });
})();
```

The error

```
{
  ...
  code: 400,
  errors: [ { message: 'Invalid Input', domain: 'global', reason: 'invalid' } ]
}
```

I don't see what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My node is a bit rusty but you need to delignate to a user on the workspace domain.  This is the user on the domain that has access.  Make sure that you have configured domain wide deligation.

```
client.subject = user;
```

Full example

```
const getClient = async (scopes: string[], user: string)=>{
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    credentials: SRVC_ACCOUNT_CREDS,
    scopes: scopes
  });
  const client = await auth.getClient();
  client.subject = user;
  return client;
};
```

Comment: I have seen examples like this, but I don't understand why I would need to delegate to a specific user. Do you have any pointer to the documentation explaining this? My assumption was that when you use a service account you don't need to perform operations on behalf of a specific user.

Comment: Ok, I found it: [Learn about authentication and authorization](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/auth-overview) and [Understanding service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-overview).

I still find it weird having to specify a real user to access API data. If you want to discover which users are admin you need to know an admin...

Comment: Well you would only be using a service account from your own domain.  In theory you would know who the admin is.   Service accounts are like dummy users they dont have any access until you tell them who they are.   in this case admin